# How to call a Firestore unsubscribe function from another function in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function that runs upon a click. It basically starts a Firestore listener to grab messages. It also has an unsubscribe function declared which I am trying to call from another function:

```
const getMessages = (uid) => {

        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('Chats').doc(uid).collection('Messages');

        const query = ref.where("uid", "==", uid).orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(25);  



      const unsubFromMessages = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {

                            if (snapshot.empty) {

                                console.log('No matching documents.');                                
                                
                            }
                                                  
                                snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                                   
                                    
                                if (change.type === 'removed') {
                    
                                console.log(change.doc.data().content)
                    
                                } else if (change.type === 'added') {                
                                
                                 
                                    setMessages(prevFiles => ([...prevFiles, {
                                    id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data()
                                        }]))                          
                                    
                                // setTimeout( this.scrollToBottom(), 2000)
                                
                                }
                    
                                
                                });
                                }, (error) => {console.log(error)});             

   }
```

As you can see inside of it, I declare a function to unsubscribe from the Firestore listener (const unsubFromMessages = query.onSnapshot). I want to be able to call this "unsubFromMessages" function upon another button click from another function which basically closes a chat.

Here's that closeChat function:

```
const closeChat = () => {    
    setMessages([]);
    unsubFromMessages();        
}
```

Unfortunately, the closeChat function can not access the unsubFromMessages function to unsubscribe from the Firestore listener. I get the following error:

```
Line 177:5:  'unsubFromMessages' is not defined  no-undef
```

I know how to do it in a class component where I would simply declare the function as this.unsubFromMessages = ... and then call it from any other function but I can not figure out how to do it in a functional component. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the `unsubFromMessages` callback in a React ref and access it in the other click hander.

```
const unsubFromMessagesRef = React.useRef();

...

const getMessages = (uid) => {
  ...
  const unsubFromMessages = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => { ..... };

  unsubFromMessagesRef.current = unsubFromMessages;

  ...
}

...

const closeChat = () => {    
  setMessages([]);
  unsubFromMessagesRef.current && unsubFromMessagesRef.current();        
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe when the component unmounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    unsubFromMessagesRef.current && unsubFromMessagesRef.current()
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you  this answer saved me